# Problem passing bash output to a python script

Tags: python, bash

I'm fairly new to programming and I searched the internet for a way to pass bash output to a Python script.

I came up with this in bash.

```
XAS_SVN=`svn info` 
ssh hudson@test "python/runtests.py $XAS_SVN"
```

And this in python.

```
import sys
print sys.argv[1]
```

When I `echo $SVN_INFO` I get the result.

> Path: . URL:
>   //svn/rnd-projects/testing/python
>   Repository Root:
>   //svn/rnd-projects Repository
>   UUID:
>   d07d5450-0a36-4e07-90d2-9411ff75afe9
>   Revision: 140 Node Kind: directory
>   Schedule: normal Last Changed Author:
>   Roy van der Valk Last Changed Rev: 140
>   Last Changed Date: 2009-06-09 14:13:29
>   +0200 (Tue, 09 Jun 2009)

However the python script just prints the following.

> Path:

Why is this and how can I solve this? I the $SVN_INFO variable not of string type?

I know about the subprocess module and the Popen function, but I don't think this is a solution since the python script runs on another server.

Comment: Why was af's answer validated, it doesn't actually work, you can't expand a variable inside single quotes (try `echo '$PATH').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to put in quotes your input to python/runtest.py because otherwise argv[1] gets it only up to the first space. Like this:

```
ssh hudson@test "python/runtest.py \"$XAS_SVN\""
```

Comment: Did you test this? If you use single quotes, the variable XAS_SVN won't be expanded.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I had a little mix-up when testing my un-edited answer, which was like it is now. I tested it with different shell and it handled the quotes differently. My bad.

Comment: First it didn't work, but after your edit it works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have spaces in the variable, you need to escape them or read all the arguments in your script:

```
print ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])
```

But it might be better to use stdin/stdout to communicate, especially if there can be some characters susceptible to be interpreted by the shell in the output (like "`$').
In the python script do:

```
for l in sys.stdin:
     sys.stdout.write(l)
```

and in shell:

```
svn info | ssh hudson@test python/runtests.py
```